# Why does VS Code fail type acquisition for Vue?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have a project directory with just three files:

```
test-proj/
  hello.js
  index.html
  jsconfig.json
```

Where `hello.js` looks like this:

```js
const a = jQuery('<div>');
const b = React.Component;
const c = Vue({ el: '#app' });
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="./hello.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

`jsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true
  }
}
```

When I open the `test-proj` directory and open `hello.js`, VS Code's type checker reports three errors:

[image: Errors for jQuery, React, Vue]

Now, I modified `jsconfig.json` so that VS Code will automatically acquire types for all three:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
      "jquery",
      "react",
      "vue"
    ]
  }
}
```

...which makes VS Code recognize that jQuery and React can be used in my script. However, as you see here, it still does not recognize Vue:

[image: Error for Vue only]

TLDR: Why does VS Code fail to acquire type definitions for Vue, when it can do so for React and jQuery?

(Note: This is not a Node.js project. I do not have `package.json` or `node_modules/` under my project directory. I also checked my globally installed `npm` packages, just to be sure, but I do not have `react` or `jquery` installed.)

Answer (score 0):

I examined the Automatic Type Acquisition cache in my PC, which is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\3.8\`

The immediate cause seems to be a missing entry in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\3.8\node_modules\types-registry\index.json`. It's a ~560KB JSON file which contains the latest version numbers for various NPM packages under the `@types` scope.

For some reason, this JSON file does not contain an entry for `vue`, even though the `@types/vue` package exists on NPM. Strangely enough, it does contain entries for several packages that depend on Vue, such as `vue-markdown` and `vue-ls`.

When I added `"vue-ls"` to my `jsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
      "jquery",
      "react",
      "vue-ls"
    ]
  }
}
```

...TypeScript downloaded `@types/vue-ls` into its cache. This pulls in the type definitions in the `vue` package, which makes the type checks work for Vue.js.